# python multiply two collection counters

Tags: python, collections, counter, dot-product, python-collections

Python collection counter
Curious if there is a better way to do this. Overriding a Counter class method?
The built-in multiply produces the dot product of two counters

```
from collections import Counter
a = Counter({'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1})
b = Counter({'b': 8, 'c': 4, 'a': 2})    
newcounter = Counter()
for x in a.elements():
    for y in b.elements():
        if x == y:
             newcounter[x] = a[x]*b[y]

$ newcounter
Counter({'b': 32, 'c': 8, 'a': 2})
```

Comment: Beware that iterating over `.elements()` gives elements in arbitrary order. Unless `a.elements()` happens to be identical to `b.elements()`, the result will be meaningless. You probably want to iterate over `sorted(a.keys())` instead, then calculate `a[key]*b[key]`

Comment: Suggest you change your example to `b = Counter({'c': 4, 'a': 2, 'b':8})` to stress that.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `a` and `b` always have the same keys, you can achieve this with a dictionary comprehension as follows:

```
a = Counter({'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1})
b = Counter({'b': 8, 'c': 4, 'a': 2})
c = Counter({k:a[k]*b[k] for k in a})
print(c)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'b': 32, 'c': 8, 'a': 2})
```

Comment: Bah, yes, I think I better delete this comment not to confuse others.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the *intersection* of the keys if you don't have identical dicts:

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter({'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1, "d":4})
b = Counter({'b': 8, 'c': 4, 'a': 2})

# just .keys() for python3
print Counter(({k: a[k] * b[k] for k in a.viewkeys() & b}))
Counter({'b': 32, 'c': 8, 'a': 2})
```

Or if you want to join both you can *or* the dicts and use dict.get:

```
from collections import Counter

a = Counter({'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1, "d":4})
b = Counter({'b': 8, 'c': 4, 'a': 2})


print Counter({k: a.get(k,1) * b.get(k, 1) for k in a.viewkeys() | b})
Counter({'b': 32, 'c': 8, 'd': 4, 'a': 2})
```

If you wanted to be able to use the * operator on the Counter dicts you would have to roll your own:

```
class _Counter(Counter):
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return _Counter({k: self[k] * other[k] for k in self.viewkeys() & other})

a = _Counter({'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1, "d": 4})
b = _Counter({'b': 8, 'c': 4, 'a': 2})

print(a * b)
```

Which would give you:

```
_Counter({'b': 32, 'c': 8, 'a': 2})
```

If you wanted inplace:

```
from collections import Counter


class _Counter(Counter):
    def __imul__(self, other):
        return _Counter({k: self[k] * other[k] for k in self.viewkeys() & other})
```

Output:

```
In [28]: a = _Counter({'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1, "d": 4})

In [29]: b = _Counter({'b': 8, 'c': 4, 'a': 2})

In [30]: a *= b

In [31]: a
Out[31]: _Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 32, 'c': 8})
```

Comment: that self.viewkeys() was (probably) what I was after. Thanks. My first version of overriding the __mul__ method did not change the object.

Comment: No worries,  there are multiple set operations you can use on dict view objects https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Comment: Wherever there is `collections` or `itertools` there you'll find @PadraicCunningham .. :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit better:

```
a = Counter({'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1})
b = Counter({'b': 8, 'c': 4, 'a': 2})    

newcounter = Counter({k:a[k]*v for k,v in b.items()})

>>> newcounter
Counter({'b': 32, 'c': 8, 'a': 2})
```